# Is it mandatory to use Launch Screen File to support iPhone 6/6Plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, iphone-6-plus

I have only Default-568h@2x.png and Default-568h@3x.png in my bundle. When I execute the application in iPhone 6 and 6 Plus the app automatically does some scaling and displays the app utilising full screen size.

But when i use some .xib file as "Launch Screen File", the app stops scaling and does not displays for full screen, has various UI issues.

Is it mandatory to have launch file, if I need to support iOS 8 / iPhone 6 / iPhone  Plus?

Is there any chance for the app to get rejected if the app does not use LAUNCH FILE?

Please let me know your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your storyboard for your launch screen now.

http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/

Answer (score 0):

NO.
LaunchScreen xib is a quick way to detect main screen. 
Depending upon the main screen, OS runs your app and determines screen width and height.

Another approach is just to add launch images for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus instead of LaunchScreen file.

NOTE: Apple is motivating to use LaunchScreen, because it is a one file launch image. It can also be used for pads as well. Single file multi purpose.

Comment: In iPhone 6+ iOS 10, only in test flight build I have an issue where on click of app. icon, launch image is same as app. icon enlarged and then later splash screen is loaded. This is happening recently and that too only in test flight. No change in xCode version. Do we need Launch Image Source and Launch Source File to be set in General Tab ?